# chmod rx invalid

Tags: chmod

```
jaime@OpticaOmegaPlus:~$ echo 'date %T' >/tmp/midate; chmod rx /tmp/midate; /tmp/midate
chmod: invalid mode: ‘rx’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
-bash: /tmp/midate: Permission denied
```

Could someone tell me why it does not work

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong.

```
$ echo 'date +%T' >> /tmp/Temp_date && chmod +rx /tmp/Temp_date && /tmp/Temp_date
08:32:18
```

- You need to add `+` sign before `rx`.
- You need to add `+` sign before `%T` to ensure it recognized by `date`.
- With all command fail, meaning you have not add content to file named `midate` on `/tmp`, that's why bash refuse to execute. As it was not valid script.

Comment: Can we be sure the OP intended `+rw` (rather than `=rw` for example)? Also AFAIK space after the redirection operator is optional.

Comment: Yes, that maybe true.... we'll just wait for OP to inform us what he want.

Comment: @steeldriver does that mean redirection with or without space produce the same result? I'm sorry, I don't know much about bash script etc..

Comment: Yes it should produce the same result - did you try it?

Comment: Well that seems the case ! Im gonna edit my answer now, thanks for pointing out @steeldriver

Comment: No problem - it's a solid answer otherwise